# Jenkins: invalid java version

Tags: jenkins

[image]

Installed jenkins freshly gives this error.

Just expecting it run smoothly

Comment: [Jenkins requires Java 11 or 17 since Jenkins 2.357 and LTS 2.361.1.](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/administration/requirements/java/)

Answer (score 0):

The message “invalid Java version” is telling you that you need a supported version of Java. Jenkins supports Java 11 and Java 17 versions. So, you should install and configure Java 11 for jenkins LTS version or Java 17 for latest version.

check the official Jenkins download page from [here](https://www.jenkins.io/download/)!

Answer (score 0):

I encountered an issue when trying to upgrade the Java version used by Jenkins on my system. Initially, I had Java 11 installed and running smoothly. However, when attempting to upgrade to Java 17, I encountered an error message stating that the new Java version was unsupported.

Upon further investigation, I discovered that this issue was related to the Jenkins Daemon configuration. The Jenkins Daemon was originally set up to support Java 8 and Java 11 versions exclusively. It lacked support for Java 17.

To address this, I manually added support for Java 17 in the Jenkins Daemon configuration. This allowed Jenkins to recognize and use the new Java 17 version correctly. Consequently, I was able to upgrade Jenkins to the latest Java version without any further issues.

```
sudo systemctl stop jenkins
nano /etc/init.d/jenkins
```

Find Supported Java Version List (It is manily on line number 54,55,56.

```
sudo update-alternatives --config java
```

Select New Java Version.

```
systemctl daemon-reload
sudo systemctl start jenkins
sudo systemctl status jenkins
```